# How can i change the text background blur padding?

Tags: html, css

I tried to get a background blur effect to a text using:

```
backdrop-filter: blur;
```

It works, but I want the padding to be smaller. How can I do that?

**P.S:** I'm new to all that things

Comment: It's helpful if you provide us the code you're working on – in this case your CSS and HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS `padding` property on the same element that you've applied `backdrop-filter` to. You can set the amount of padding in pixels. The following will apply 20 pixels of padding to each side of your element:

`padding: 20px;`